# Do input and get return message from console like Command Prompt in Windows

Tags: java, command-line

In the Command Prompt(cmd) of the Windows OS:

```
C:\>execution.exe --login user
Enter password:
Success
```

The work flow is entering the command->system returns message "Enter password:"->Input password->system returns message "Success".
How to do that in my code?
Here is mine, but It doesn't work.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("execution.exe --login user");
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
writer.write("mypassword\n");
writer.flush();
writer.close();
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
                     InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

// read the output from the command
System.out.println("System returns message:\n");
String s = null;
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
}
// read any errors from the attempted command
    System.out.println("System returns error message:\n");
while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: What error/output you get?

Comment: Nothing. I debugged and the program cannot go through this "s = stdInput.readLine()".
All of output of the console is: "System returns message:"